# Which "Batman Beyond" episode has dream life simulation machines?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman, episode-identification, cartoon

There was this episode in Batman Beyond, which starts off with a bunch of people stuck in some anti-gravitational bubbles, dreaming about a great life (I remember one girl was dreaming of her boyfriend asking her to marry her, and this one dude was dreaming about being a rock-star and all the celebrity that came with it). They were like some sort of junkies, dreaming of a good/better life, hooked up to a simulation machine.

If I remember correctly this whole scene is set in a sort of a shady cellar and I believe it is the Joker who is behind this whole setup.

Anyway, I would really like to watch this episode again, for inspiration in writing something related, but I can't remember which episode it was.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IMDb's episode list for the [second season of Batman Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0147746/episodes?season=2) has the following description for "Hooked Up":

> Batman investigates a ring of troubled kids who are so addicted to powerful virtual reality fantasies that they will do anything to continue them.

There is a good chance that this is the episode you are looking for.

Comment: Wasn't there another episode where at the end Mad Stan was in one of these, thinking he blew up city hall?

Comment: @Nu'Daq Yes. Spellbinder tried to frame Terry (aka. Batman) for murdering Mad Stan, when in fact what Commissioner Barbara Gordon saw was merely an illusion. It turns out Mad Stan was alive all along. At the end, he's seen blowing up a library(?), whilst the officers are wondering why he looks so happy (since they can't see what he's dreaming about).

Answer (score 23):

You're thinking of the episode "[Hooked Up](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Hooked_Up)".

The plot synopsis:

> Batman discovers several teenagers addicted to a new form of virtual reality, which causes harmful side effects and pushes many of its users to crime to pay for their habit. Things worsen when Max, who has been pressing Terry to let her take a more active role in his crimefighting, investigates the technology and becomes hooked on it herself.

The virtual reality shows the user the world that they want the most. It's been a while since I watched that episode, and the synopsis doesn't mention anyone being proposed to in their fantasy, but one of the fantasies shown is a guy being a rock star at a concert.

Users of Spellbinder's device were encased within a sort of sphere as you described.

[image: screencap 1]

[image: screencap 2]

[This site](http://www.watchcartoononline.com/batman-beyond-season-2-episode-21-hooked-up) has the episode available for streaming.

Spellbinder also appeared in the episode "[Spellbound](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Spellbound)", which DOES include a scene at a wedding.

[image: screencap 3]

Comment: He was in a few episodes, kinda like the Batman Beyond version of the Scarecrow.

Comment: @MikeBrown, right, I was just pointing out the other episode because of the wedding scene. It wasn't in the episode that the OP was looking for, but it's entirely possible that the two episodes just got combined in their head.